# How do I delete product with axios.delete in my React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, react-hooks

So I have a basic spring rest API that can store dummy product data and on my admin page, when I enter the product ID in my input element, I want it to be deleted. I am using Axios in my app so preferably can the solution be with it(but its not important). I will attach the RemoveProduct component and my rest API endpoint.

```
const RemoveProduct = () => {
    
    const [id, findId] = useState('')
    const deleteProduct = (id) => {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/webapp/api/product/delete/${id}`)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
    }
  return (
    <div>
      <input type='text' onChange={(e) => findId(parseInt(e.target.value))}/>
      <button onClick={() => deleteProduct(id)}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RemoveProduct
```

below is my rest API endpoint

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteUser(@PathVariable long id) {
        for (Product product: productList) {
            if (product.getId() == id) {
                productList.remove(product);
                return new ResponseEntity<>("Product successfully deleted.", HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Product not found.", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

Comment: After your delete request the product is removed from the server side list, but the list you might be using on the frontend to render the products is still having that product. You can either do the delete request, wait for the response and remove the product from the ui list, or you can send the delete request to backend and reload the products list on ui via http request.  Make sure your backend and frontend lists are in sync.

Comment: you can filter the list and set it to state from UI after success response from API as mentioned above or send the products list after deletion as response from server so you can set the list to state